# Algorthim to create a mesh between two sets of points

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh

Is there an algorithm to create a mesh between two lists of 3D points, each list forms a full loop?

[Example Image](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2exa3d5.jpg)

In the linked image the Red dots are the first set and the blue are the second, the grey is the desired output of triangles connecting the two sets filling the gap between.

This [image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/34yuxz7.jpg) shows what I would like to do exactly in 3d , The purple points form the outline of the first terrain and the other points forms the outline of a hole in the second terrain, the algorithm should create a mesh to fill the gap between the inner and outer outline.

Comment: Please show us What have you tried?

Comment: What you'll end up with will be a tet-mesh, that connects the outer surface with the inner surface, when done in 3D. Is this what you need? If it is alright, can you tell why you need this, in 3d.

Comment: I've edited the question and added another image and an explanation to what i'm trying to do exactly.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749126/surface-reconstruction-from-2-planar-contours) has references to some meshing techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify if the following method works. The basic idea is, as you loop around the inner nodes, you get the nearest from the outer one and add an edge. The nearest on the outer loop should be either the one already set, or one of its neighbours. So you can exploit this, like so:

```
innernode = firstnode(innerloop)
outernode = NULL

while(innernode) do

    if(outernode) then
        //For every new node, check if the outer node is the nearest, 
        //or if any of its neighbours are
        newouternode = find_nearest_among(outernode, prev(outernode), 
                                            next(outernode), innernode)
        if(newouternode != outernode) then
            //If we found a new node, add an extra edge, 
            //otherwise, we'll have quads
            //The figure shows why this is needed.
            make_edge(innernode, outernode)
            outernode = newouternode 
        end
    else
        //the first time, find the closest node in the outer loop)
        outernode = find_nearest(outerloop, innernode)
    end
    //continue making an edge to the outernode, we're closest to
    make_edge(innernode, outernode)

    //move on
    innernode = next(innernode)
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arun, I've verified it and it works as expected for the above use case, I was also looking for a generic algorithm and i think that this one might be helpful for anyone in the future http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~zoum/projects/TriMultPoly/

Answer (score 0):

Input are two loops of points, such that one loop is in inside other loop.

Idea is to connect points by traversing loops in same direction (parallel.) Find one point in outer and one point in inner loop such that segment connecting them doesn't intersect any loop. There are two possibilities to move to next segment, move point on inner loop or move point on outer loop. Test these two segments for intersection with loops, and (if needed) quality of triangle produced by last segment and next segment, and decide next segment to use. Repeat moving segment until whole points return to initial segment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I think what you are suggesting here won't work for my problem or in 3D in general, I've linked a new image: [Crack](http://oi60.tinypic.com/34yuxz7.jpg) as you see the purple dots which forms an outline need to be connected with triangles with the other set of dots which forms another outline to fill the crack.