# Surface reconstruction from 2 planar contours

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, triangulation

There is a class of algorithms for triangulation between two planar contours. These algorithms try to make a "good triangulation" to fill a space between these contours:

[image]

One of them ([Optimal surface reconstruction from planar contours](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.6280&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) is based on the dynamic programming technique and uses a cost function for determining which triangulation is acceptable according to the minimum cost.

A minimal triangle area as a cost function makes a good result in most of cases ([Triangulation of Branching Contours using Area Minimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.24.9914)), but, unfortunately, not in all of them.

For example when you have two rectangle contours that are shifted from each other.

[image: Failed Example]

As you can see, according to the minimal area criteria, all points from the contour \alpha will be connected to the point A of the contour \beta, that is not true (a correct triangulation must be a "tube" through both curves, instead of two tetrahedrons).

So my questions are:

1) Does any algorithm that deals with two contours better than the dynamic programming based one exist?

2) If not, which criteria for the cost function can provide a better result?

Comment: Are you sure that your second diagram is what the dynamic program will do? Three of the four edges in B do not participate in a triangle connecting the contours, which seems as though it should be a constraint violation.

Comment: Four points from B also will be connected to the single point from A, yes. It will looks like two tetrahedrons.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is adjusting the cost function with code that will detect such cases. In particular summed length of all newly created triangles from vertices of one of the polygons should be equal to that polygon's perimeter. In above case both of the tetrahedrons summed perimeter would yield zero and cost function should invalidate the result.

Comment: On page 4 in your second reference it is stated: "This problem can be mitigated by first scaling and translating the contours so that their bounding boxes align." You should be able to apply this principle to sufficiently avoid the scenario in the lower figure.